Understanding this particular usage of たり
For a bit of context, 清香 has been looking after a patient in a coma. Occasionally, she would converse with her even though she was in unconscious state.

I am uncertain how this sentence is understood:

昏睡状態でも話しかけたり外界からの刺激で状況が変わったーなんて話もあるけど

The たり part is throwing me off. It seems like 話しかけたり is an example of 外界からの刺激, so 話しかけたり外界からの刺激 can be written as 話しかけるなど外界からの刺激, right? The loose translation of this sentence would be "there are stories when patient's condition change after receiving even external stimulation like getting talked to even while in coma"? Does 昏睡状態でも modify 話しかけたり only?

Does 昏睡状態でも modify 話しかけたり only? -- 昏睡状態でも modifies 状況が変わった

I was going to make this a comment, but it seems more to be answer?
For the highlighted sentence, it makes sense to me if you parse it as

昏睡状態でも話しかけたり外界からの刺激で状況が変わったーなんて話もあるけど
There are accounts [of how,] even if someone's in a coma, their condition changes through stimuli from the outside world, things like talking to them.

Does that work?  Or am I missing your point?

「話しかけたり外界からの刺激を受けたりして」というふうに「VたりVたりする」となっていないし、また「話しかけられたりといった外界からの刺激」というふうに前半（「話しかけたり」）が体言修飾できる形にもなっていないから、文法的に気持ち悪いってことではないかな・・・と思います。で、この２つのどちらかによって、訳し方(細かい意味)も、ちょっと変わってきますよね。

@chocolate I was wondering whether I was off since my way of parsing it would seem to require an ellipses between 話しかけたり and 外界から... as if the first half of the sentence was left dangling....
